# Is it possible to resize an image without importing?

Tags: image-processing

1. If we have a list of 1000 ULRs which refer to image files of the following form:

http://...file1.jpg
http://...file2.jpg
...
http://...file1000.jpg

Objective: We want to resize each image (e.g. 100x100 pixels) without importing the images?

Is it possible to do this without reading the files in? This would save memory and increase speed.

This question arises e.g. in machine learning.

Comment: I would use an external tool e.g. jpegtran

Comment: You might find `ImageFileApply` or `ImageFileFilter` useful here.

Comment: Thank you very much for both comments.

Comment: If you are using this for training a neural network, you should have a look at the `NetEncoder` documentation as well. There is some documentation for out-of-core batch generation somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. 

I think you address the out-of-core training by using a generating function.

Wolfram has written a very good summary with examples on out-of-core training (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html)

I have successfully applied generating function.